# Android EditText in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, keyboard

I want to implement a search. But unfortunately edit text must be in recycler view. I have multiple types of items.
When user enters a letter I refresh whole adapter, searching is done locally. That means that keyboard disappears and edit text is losing focus, because of this constant updating.
I managed to fix it showing keyboard and focus an edit manually while binding.

```
 if (item.inEditableMode) {
            edit_text.requestFocus()
            showKeyboard(edit_text)
 }
```

But edit text works not that good as I expect. A problem can be seen when user types fast or wants to clear input.
Thanks for help.

Layout:
[image]

Comment: If you include screenshot / screen recording of the UI and problem, it'd help a lot

Comment: Why `edit text must be in recycler view`?

Comment: I've posted layout. It must be in a recycler, because it must be scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"unfortunately edit text must be in recycler view" - I bet it do NOT have to be a part of `RecyclerView` not part of `Adapter` list item `View`. better inspect your layout architecture instead of posted workarounds with hiding-showing (blinking) keyboard

besides that even when it must be then don't notify whole `Adapter` with `notifyDataSetChanged()`, instead use `notifyItemChanged(...)` - notify range of of your items, but not list item with `EditText` - it won't be redrawn, so keyboard should stay visible and focus kept on that field. still this isn't good approach, your `EditText` should be separated from `RecyclerView` almost for shure

Comment: I've added an example layout. I have no other idea how put it other way except in one adapter. I would love to edit text scrollable and outside recycler. Edit text is sometimes on a list, sometimes not. But if is always on second position.

Comment: OK I fixed my problem. When I am at edit mode I do notifyItemRangeChanged from a third item. :)